# If M1 and M2 are 2 TM’s such that L(M1) = L(M2) , then which of the following conditions are true?

Tags: automata

(a) On every input on which M1, doesn’t halt, M2 doesn’t halt.
(b) On every i/p on which M1 halts, M2 halts too.
(c) On every i/p which M1 accepts, M2 halts.

How to approach this question ?

Comment: What do you think, why? (Please write out "i/p", it's no harder to type and harder to understand at first.)

Comment: No idea sorry , I am not getting that when both accept same languages then obviously both turing machines will be same then obviously if M1 halts then M2 will also halt on every machine , so answer should be b

Comment: Well, they're not necessarily *the same* in details, they may implement different algorithms, but the results are the same.